# MysqL: Perform fulltext search over multiple columns and 100 % match

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to do a fulltext search over multiple columns in a MySQL database, only using 1 Input field to search for addresses.

So far my code works but I also get rows returned where not all search words are present.

```
SELECT *, ((1.3 * (MATCH (city) AGAINST ('+$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))
+ (0.6 * (MATCH (name, zip, str) AGAINST ('+$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS relevance
FROM service
WHERE (MATCH (name, city, zip, str) AGAINST ('+$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
HAVING relevance > 0 ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 10
```

This could return sth like:

```
$search = "Anderson City ZIP"

1. Anderson, City, ZIP, street x
2. Anderson, City, ZIP, street y
3. Smith, City, ZIP, street x
```

So line 3 is wrong because it does not contain `Anderson` but `Smith`.

I already tried to add the + operator in the `$search` string (`Anderson City ZIP --> +Anderson +City +ZIP`) but then the result often does not show anything.

Is it possible to return only rows with 100 % match?

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign is the good thing to do but you have to be sure that one of the strings you are searching for is not in more than 50% of the rows of your table.

Also consider using  quotes to match the full expression: +"Anderson City ZIP"

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help. 1st: * wildcard does not work any longer!? 2nd: if I type in the Name I get a result but as soon as I add the city I won't get any result. Is it possible to turn off the "stopword behavior"? I think that my table is small enough to handle it (from Performance Point of view).